# Why am I not able to login to Quora using an automation package like Selenium or Watir?

Tags: python, ruby, selenium, watir

I am able to login into Facebook and other websites ? Selenium is not even filling out the username or password ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.quora.com/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
elem.send_keys("my_email")

elem_pass = driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
elem_pass.send_keys("password")

elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.close()
```

The Ruby-Watir Code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'http://www.quora.com/'


browser.text_field(:name => 'email').set 'my_email'
browser.text_field(:name => 'pass').set 'my_password'
```

Comment: Thanks but Quora does not login with JS turned off. Any alternative.

Comment: Any ideas on how to inject JS on a page when it has been turned of by selenium ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to find the element. If I am correct there are the various option for login into it may be that's why it is not able to find it.

TRY THIS:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chromedriver_loc = r"chromedriver path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_loc)
#PhantomJS_loc = r"phantomJS path"
#driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=PhantomJS_loc)

url = "https://www.quora.com/"
driver.get(url)
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".regular_login [name=email]"))
)
elem.send_keys("type here email")

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".regular_login [name=password]"))
)

elem.send_keys("type here password")
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```